# How to make a local printer available over IPP?

Tags: windows-7, printing

I would like to make a printer connected to a Windows 7 computer available over [IPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol).

How can I do this using built-in features of Windows, or using some third-party software (free software is preferred).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install IIS. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx. With it installed you should be able to share out your printers.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126092(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Can you explain how to install the IPP Service on Windows 7, once you have IIS installed? On Server 2008 this is a role service, but Windows 7 does not have "roles" and an IPP Server is not available in "Turn Windows features on or off".